# SQL Server Group by Value !=Previous value without Cursor loop

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, group-by

I have to write a T-SQL to get over speed rows as (Max/Min/Avg) but with  condition that if any row < speedvalue then the (Max/Min/avg) will be show for the new over speed rows

For example this is my database table and it have flag if this row is overspeed or not

```
rownum  Time                overspeed   overspeedrowid
1   2015-12-06 06:18:46.283 0           0
2   2015-12-06 06:19:46.283 1           0
3   2015-12-06 06:20:46.283 1           0
4   2015-12-06 06:21:46.283 0           0
5   2015-12-06 06:22:46.283 0           0
6   2015-12-06 06:23:46.283 1           0
7   2015-12-06 06:24:46.283 1           0
8   2015-12-06 06:25:46.283 1           0
9   2015-12-06 06:26:46.283 1           0
10  2015-12-06 06:27:46.283 0           0
11  2015-12-06 06:28:46.283 0           0
12  2015-12-06 06:29:46.283 0           0
13  2015-12-06 06:30:46.283 1           0
14  2015-12-06 06:31:46.283 1           0
15  2015-12-06 06:32:46.283 1           0
16  2015-12-06 06:33:46.283 0           0
17  2015-12-06 06:34:46.283 0           0
18  2015-12-06 06:35:46.283 1           0
19  2015-12-06 06:36:46.283 0           0
20  2015-12-06 06:37:46.283 0           0
21  2015-12-06 06:38:46.283 0           0
22  2015-12-06 06:39:46.283 1           0
23  2015-12-06 06:40:46.283 1           0
```

My plan is to use the following

1. Loop over rows and if current != prev and prev = 0 then new overspeedrowid value
2. If  current = prev and prev = 1 then current overspeedrowid = prev overspeedrowid
3. Select from calculated table min/max group by overspeedrowid

So the calculated table must be like this

```
rownum  Time                overspeed   overspeedrowid
1   2015-12-06 06:18:46.283 0           0
2   2015-12-06 06:19:46.283 1           1
3   2015-12-06 06:20:46.283 1           1
4   2015-12-06 06:21:46.283 0           0
5   2015-12-06 06:22:46.283 0           0
6   2015-12-06 06:23:46.283 1           2
7   2015-12-06 06:24:46.283 1           2
8   2015-12-06 06:25:46.283 1           2
9   2015-12-06 06:26:46.283 1           2
10  2015-12-06 06:27:46.283 0           0
11  2015-12-06 06:28:46.283 0           0
12  2015-12-06 06:29:46.283 0           0
13  2015-12-06 06:30:46.283 1           3
14  2015-12-06 06:31:46.283 1           3
15  2015-12-06 06:32:46.283 1           3
16  2015-12-06 06:33:46.283 0           0
17  2015-12-06 06:34:46.283 0           0
18  2015-12-06 06:35:46.283 1           4
19  2015-12-06 06:36:46.283 0           0
20  2015-12-06 06:37:46.283 0           0
21  2015-12-06 06:38:46.283 0           0
22  2015-12-06 06:39:46.283 1           5
23  2015-12-06 06:40:46.283 1           5
```

- I tried a cursor but it takes much time as the production data is about 2,000,000 rows.
- I tried `Update` with join row-1 and compare row-1 with current its fast  not corrected as it update only the second row

Here is what I have done but its only update the second row ,

```
update #temp1 
set #temp1.overspeedrowid = @a, @a = @a + 1 
from #temp1 
left join #temp1 prev on prev.rownum = #temp1.rownum - 1 
where 
     (#temp1.overspeed != prev.overspeed and #temp1.overspeed = 1)

update #temp1 
set #temp1.overspeedrowid = prev. overspeedrowid 
from #temp1 
left join #temp1 prev on prev.rownum = #temp1.rownum - 1 
where 
     (#temp1.overspeed = prev.overspeed and #temp1.overspeed = 1)
```

Comment: Tip: As shown by Gordon Linoff's answer, it's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012+, you can use `lag()` followed by a "condition" cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       (case when overspeed = 0 then 0
             else sum(OverSpeedFlag) over (order by time)
        end) as overspeedrowid
from (select t.*,
             (case when lag(overspeed) over (order by time) = 0 and overspeed = 1
                   then 1 else 0 
              end) as OverSpeedFlag
      from #temp1 t
     ) t;
```